# find the matrix of a linear transformation $X1\oplus X2\to X1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am given a linear transformation $p:X_1\oplus X_2\to X_1$, which means that $p(x_1+x_2)=x_1$ where $x_1 \in X_1$ and $x_2 \in X_2$. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are subspaces of a real space $X$. 
I am also given the bases $(e_1, e_2,..., e_m)$ which is the base of $X_1$ and $(e_{m+1}, e_{m+2},..., e_n)$ which is the base of $X_2$. Here vectors $e_1$, $e_2$, ... $e_n$ are vectors from the standard base of $\mathbb R^n$.

I understand that the vectors from $X_1 \oplus X_2$ can be represented as linear combinations of vectors $e_1,...,e_n$ and when I transform that linear combination I should get a vector that is represented as a linear transformation of vectors $e_1, ..., e_m$.

After I do this, I get stuck and don't know how to continue to find the needed matrix. Any ideas would be helpful, since I am kind of clueless on what the next step is.

Comment: Note that typing `$X_1$` produces $X_1$, as opposed to $X1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks, I was trying to figure that out, but couldn't find it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
p(a_1 e_1 + \cdots + a_m e_m + a_{m+1}e_{m+1} + \cdots + a_n e_n) = 
a_1 e_1 + \cdots + a_ne_n
$$
As such, the matrix of the transformation is the matrix $M$ satisfying
$$
M \pmatrix{a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_{m} \\ a_{m+1} \\ \vdots \\ a_n} = 
\pmatrix{a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_{m}}
$$

Comment: Can we solve this like this: 

Let $\ T_{mxn}$ be the matrix of this operator and $\ I_{nxn} $ be the identity matrix formed from vectors $\ \{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ and $\ Y_{mxn}$ be the matrix of the results and we conclude from $\ T*I=Y $ that $\ T=Y$

Comment: Excuse my typo; see my latest edit.  To your comment: note that the actual vectors $e_i$ from our basis will have nothing to do with our matrix.

Comment: Oh! I missed the end of your question where you elaborate on the $e_i$.  Yes, you're right.  The matrix is
$$
T = \pmatrix{I & 0}
$$

Comment: @CTSnake could you elaborate a bit more? I understand the idea but I am not sure why the dimensions of $T$ are $mxn$

Comment: @ivana14 when you form the LT matrix the number of rows "m" is equal to the dimension of codomain and the number of columns "n" is the dimension of domain.

Comment: @CTSnake right, I forgot about that. Thanks

Comment: @ivana14 You're welcome :)